# How to change hostname of a SLES11 Server

Tags: hostname, sles

How do I change and check the hostname of a SLES11 based system?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hostname` command or edit `/etc/hostname`

```
$ sudo hostname myhostname
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you, show an example, (don't forget sudo)